# JQuery independent list scrolling

Tags: jquery

I have 2 lists on one page - http://jsfiddle.net/nalsur/CneTJ/

And now I want add/create independ scrolling for each of them

How:)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap each list in a div. Give the div a height and set overflow to auto.

**Note:** In order for the scrolling to trigger, the ul list has to have a height larger than the parent div.

```
.Scrollable
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
}

<div class="Scrollable">
   <ul class="FirstUL"></ul>
</div>
<div class="Scrollable">
   <ul class="FirstUL"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: At first, thanks, seems that this is a right way, but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/nalsur/skqmy/ Ooops, my mistaje in height:100%;, after removing all works fine

Comment: Np. 100% height would definitely not work using this approach.